# Refraction Error and i am unable to extract Method error message

Tags: android-studio, flutter

> The selection does not cover a set of statements or an expression. Extend selection to a valid range.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Time Tracker'),
          elevation: 3.0),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
        Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
        ),
        ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Which method are you trying to extract?

Comment: a widget in as a Build content